# codeigniter clear view output

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, view

Is there any way possible to "clear" whats currently in the view instead of having to use a redirect?

I am implementing ajax on my site and have noticed that if I want to return a response to a ajax request with only the views I want shown,  I have to use a redirect. Other wise, if I just use

```
$this->load->view('blah');
```

it will keep the original content ( in this case a form) and just add the view on top of that. I would rather not use a redirect as I would like to keep the url the same. Any way to clear whats currently in the view without a redirect or javascript?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function updateajaxem(){


$(document).on("click", "a.ajaxem", function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();

var action=$(this).attr('href');
//alert(action);
if(action.indexOf('register')>0){

$("div#logininfo").load("http://localhost/testrun/auth/register/").fadeIn();

}
else if(action.indexOf('password')>0)
{
$("div#logininfo").load("http://localhost/testrun/auth/forgot_password/").fadeIn();

}

}); //end 

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  updateajaxem();

//$("a.ajaxem").live("click", function(e){ 


$(document).on("click","input:submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var formaction=$(this).closest('form').attr('action');
var dataString=$(this).closest('form').serialize();
alert(dataString);
//$("div#logininfo").load(formaction,data);

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: formaction,
        data: dataString,
     //   dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
alert(data);

        $("div#logininfo").html(data);
        updateajaxem();


       }// end of success

        });        





});





</script>
```

For my codeigniter, basically it ends up being a
 `redirect('whereever'); or  $this->load->view("blah");`

the codeigniter is basically the standard auth tank code , just the links and forms are "ajax-ed". So the codeigniter that works with the javascript is either just loading a view or redirecting to a another function in the controller that loads a view. nothing special. Just that only the redirect will show just the newly added view while a simple load view without a redirect will show the old content as well. Based on the suggestion by comments, looks like ill have to handle it through javascript after the ajax is performed.

but only the redirect will "clear" the current view content and show only what I want, which is usually a update message or simple html. However, the redirect requires another url change.

Also, after a few clicks my "ajaxem" class events are no longer triggered? That is why I made the updateajaxem() function and call it after each ajax reload, however, this is not working. I have been reading, will delegates only work for current and **future** elements?

Comment: Can you please show your example code? You might not think it matters, but there are ***so*** many ways to deal with this that it'd be better to show you how in your specific example.

Comment: Saw your edit. Sorry, I meant please show the Controller code, because that's where all this business is handled. Do you know about `$this->input->is_ajax_request()`?

Comment: yes, but that would require a redirect as far as I know to remove the previous content without using javascript. without using a redirect, both echo and returning just a view will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any way to clear whats currently in the view without a redirect or javascript?

Technically it's not possible to "clear" what has already been sent to the browser. If in your example even something is already displayed within the browser it is generally too late to "clear" the browser window from the server side.

This is why the redirect works, it will command the browser to navigate away from the page and obtain new output.

You could encode a command to remove fragments from the DOM and replace others, so with AJAX but that would be javascript (and not what you ask for).

As long as you have not send the output to the browser, you can clear that by using [output control functions in PHP<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). Like creating an output buffer and manipulate it before sending the output to the browser

Answer (score 0):

you can use $('body').load('url'); with jQuery, but that's about all I have to suggest.  This will perform an ajax request and replace your body with new content.  You can also implement a more robust solution with ajax loader gifs and the like.

Comment: Haha, durr...my bad for speedreading.  I figured since i wasn't thinking since it was tagged javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You using ajax , in respose echo whatever you want to stick the view.
**In PHP :**

```
if(isset($_GET['ajax'])){
$data = "<table>
<tr>
<td>Data To substitute</td>
</tr>
</table>";
}
```

**In Js:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data){
    $("#WrapperDivWhereYouWantToAddNewView").html(data);
  }
});
```

I guess , this will do.